# How to get response content from a url which is redirected, using golang

Tags: python, go, post, postman, net-http

I have made a http post request in postman and It is working fine, and also I export the python code and the response data is fine. But when I use the same code with golang syntax I am unable to get the response data.

```
import requests


headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'X-Apple-I-FD-Client-Info': '{"U":"Mozilla/5.0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Origin': 'https://iforgot.apple.com',
    'Referer': 'https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}


data = '{"id":"ali@gmail.com"}'


response = requests.post('https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid', headers=headers, data=data)
print(response.text)
print(response)
```

The Above code with http request is working fine. But in golang it is not showing the result as shown by python request.

GoLang code is:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    url := "https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid"
    method := "POST"
    // payload := strings.NewReader("{\"id\":\"ali@gmail.com\"}")

    reqBody, err := json.Marshal(map[string]string{
        "id": "ali@gmail.com",
    })
    if err != nil {
        print(err)
    }
    payload := bytes.NewBuffer(reqBody)

    log.Println("A Payload is ", payload)

    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, payload)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Payload: ", payload)
    req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01")
    req.Header.Add("X-Apple-I-FD-Client-Info", `{"U":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36","L":"en-US","Z":"GMT+05:00","V":"1.1","F":"VGa44j1e3NlY5BSo9z4ofjb75PaK4Vpjt.gEngMQEjZr_WhXTA2s.XTVV26y8GGEDd5ihORoVyFGh8cmvSuCKzIlnY6xljQlpRD_vLwoxVagmmypZHgfLMC7AeLd7FmrpwoNN5uQ4s5uQ.gEx4xUC541jlS7spjt.gEngMQEjZr_WhXTA2s.XTVV26y8GGEDd5ihORoVyFGh8cmvSuCKzIlnY6xljQlpRD_vLwoxVagmmypZHgfLMC7Awvw0BpUMnGWqbyATblVnmccbguaDeyjaY2ftckuyPBDjaY1HGOg3ZLQ0IHxVS_509K8Qai.uJtHoqvynx9MsFyxYMA1cCyecGYiMfU.a4Y.a4Vdm_69WK2iwAxMOyeMrgPuVrA1cCtTf237lY5BSp55BNlan0Os5Apw.9o0"}`)
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; param=value")
    req.Header.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36")
    req.Header.Add("Origin", "https://iforgot.apple.com")
    req.Header.Add("Referer", "https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid")
    req.Header.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
    req.Header.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9")
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

I need the same results that i get in the python.

Comment: Start by handling all errors.

Comment: @Volker Sir, I didn't get you? As there is no error.

Comment: Can you please run the few lines of go and guide me please? @Volker

Comment: The errors from `res, err := client.Do(req)` and `body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)` are unhandled. (Nitpick, unrelated to you problem but important: Do not make a http.Client for each request, this is _wrong_).

Comment: I handled these errors, and there's single http request. Please tell me in detail. 
Thanks

Comment: Handling an error is something like `if err != nil { at least log err }`. Your code does not handle the errors.

Comment: I just handled and try again. 
`res, err := client.Do(req)
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
 }
 defer res.Body.Close()
 body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
 }`

Comment: The problem is I am not getting the same results as in python with same request?
As I assume the requested url may be redirected to the new one and in python, It is handled by default.. But What can I do for this in golang?

Comment: What is the redirect series and response with Python? Are there cookies involved, which you aren't handling here?

Comment: @JimB I am running the request with same header parameters which are added in python. For your ease I have added the run able code of python and golang above.

Comment: The `X-Apple-I-FD-Client-Info` is not the same in the different code snippets in the question, but might not be the issue. When you step through it with a debugger (or prints), what is `res.StatusCode`? In Go, there is no error when the status code is in the 4xx or 5xx range, so you need to check manually

Comment: @xarantolus `X-Apple-I-FD-Client-Info` this is no issue with it, and I proper console the status code, `res.StatusCode` it is showing 200.

Comment: Running your example shows a compressed reply. Did you try decompressing it, or not requesting it compressed in the first place?

Comment: @JimB If you comment that line 
`req.Header.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")`
you'll see the results with decompressing but not yet as same in python.

Comment: Your `Content-Type` is different. Please proofread the examples throughly.

Comment: I have changed the `Content-Type` as same as in python header `application/json` but it shows empty {} response. Have you dry run the code?

Comment: @HuzaifaAhmed: yes. Are you correctly managing cookies?

Comment: Thank you @JimB , I just added the `client := &http.Client{
  Jar: cookieJar,
 }` and my issue is resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are fundamental differences in both the request you are making, and the clients you are using. The python `requests` client is automatically handling cookies and decompressing the result by default, while the Go client does not.

You are also sending a json body, but in the Go example you specify that the body is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which means it's not going to be correctly parsed by the server.

If you add a jar to handle cookies, don't request a compressed response (or alternatively decompress the response), and correctly set the content type, the Go example works as expected:

```
url := "https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid"
method := "POST"

jar, _ := cookiejar.New(nil)
client := &http.Client{Jar: jar}
req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, strings.NewReader(`{"id":"ali@gmail.com"}`))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript")
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
res, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer res.Body.Close()

body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(body))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your request is zipped, if you comment the line `req.Header.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")` you will receive a readable response.

The response is

```
{
    "appleID": {
        "sstt": "DgfLAY0Pjcyptm0jAsIIjaC1gOmtrABF4SqCgY6VpT7vUEe/SGWdtgo/3hVoF0viKGnJ7iRXiW98WMJeARITg74qvsE0afVB7YscM5yr+dBOekbsV4FpUXWDrOqXageN4Jd0wu0t2870slQJZVo/pcYGVAeTg/cTQ7sNebehroX/6NB28w8nuzUTIff0hHmEpi0LdmrDwO5iyuHXQvWtEZp7+9oQa46pUDMbvqtQ5fwHkWmQgS7ItN3IK0WAqfaiPIcMESPoH4tf2xsB0Xl/qvdw9sNetY+GjjL3WbKDAOX1TZI4LW2I4KQBHOfXXxB3MoCmVdz/9MLKVuJGkmAgyxAY0koXWmrQGgiJ6fKXZWOwXoVTqMajDWDxJSOkRzVro0MXguMYEFKdwMnM"
    },
    "validationErrors": [
        {
            "code": "errorNoAppleID",
            "message": "Please enter your Apple ID.",
            "path": "id",
            "suppressDismissal": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Which indicates that the apple Id is missing

Comment: Exactly you are very close to the scenario.

Comment: Basically It is because, the payload we are trying to add may be not added. As you see the python request it is as same. But it is showing the results 
`{
  "supportsUnlock": true,
  "supportsResetWithOtherDevice": false,
  "options": [
    "email"
  ],
  "account": {
    "name": "ali@gmail.com"
  },
  "emailAddress": "a•••••@g•••••.com",
  "rescueEmail": false,
  "emailDomain": "g•••••.com",
  "forgotPasswordFlow": true,
  "sstt": "g8xEyh58JbseV9b8zT6SIUh//RBD65gIcOUhGxQ46kW02nQIhyJEAH93yq52xuUwNiYRbYz/cT7LyVrwz7u7nAyIGMSBrDd26RcU6..."
}`

Comment: The main point is why the end result is different as i am using the same headers, payload, and http method(POST) in both Golang and python. Python is showing the desired results but I am unable to get the results in golang.